# Using Swagger with ASP.NET Boilerplate returns 400 Bad Request with POST, PUT and Delete operations. Logs indicate a problem with anti-forgery token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate

I am new to ASP.NET Boilerplate and I tried creating my first Application Service using a simple Entity.

Here's the Entity:

```
public class Category : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Domain Service:

```
public class CategoryManager : DomainService, ICategoryManager
{
    private readonly IRepository<Category> _categoryRepository;

    public CategoryManager(IRepository<Category> categoryRepository)
    {
        _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAll()
    {
        return _categoryRepository.GetAllList();
    }

    public Category GetById(int id)
    {
        return _categoryRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public Category Add(Category category)
    {
        return _categoryRepository.Insert(category);
    }


}
```

Application Service:

```
public class CategoryAppService : ApplicationService, ICategoryAppService
{
    private readonly ICategoryManager _categoryManager;

    public CategoryAppService(ICategoryManager categoryManager)
    {
        _categoryManager = categoryManager;
    }


    public ListResultDto<CategoryDto> GetAll(GetAllCategoriesInput input)
    {
        var categories = _categoryManager.GetAll();

        return new ListResultDto<CategoryDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<CategoryDto>>(categories));
    }

    public CategoryDto GetById(GetCategoryByIdInput input)
    {
        var category = _categoryManager.GetById(input.Id);
        return ObjectMapper.Map<CategoryDto>(category);
    }

    public CategoryDto Create([FromBody]CategoryDto input)
    {
        var category = _categoryManager.Add(ObjectMapper.Map<Category>(input));

        return ObjectMapper.Map<CategoryDto>(category);
    }


}
```

When I try to access the Get endpoints using swagger, everything is working as expected. But, when I try accessing the other endpoints, it returns 400 undocumented error.

[image: Example of Invoking "Create" endpoint using Swagger]

[image: Example response]

Here's some info I found in the output window about the request made with swagger:

```
    SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:62114/api/services/app/Category/Create application/json 86
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Route matched with {area = "app", action = "Create", controller = "Category"}. Executing action SampleService.Categories.AppServices.CategoryAppService.Create (SampleService.Application)
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Antiforgery.AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter[1]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Antiforgery token validation failed. The required antiforgery header value "X-XSRF-TOKEN" is not present.
SampleService.Web.Mvc> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery header value "X-XSRF-TOKEN" is not present.
SampleService.Web.Mvc>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
SampleService.Web.Mvc>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Antiforgery.AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'.
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult[1]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Executing HttpStatusCodeResult, setting HTTP status code 400
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Executed action SampleService.Categories.AppServices.CategoryAppService.Create (SampleService.Application) in 0.6744ms
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Request finished in 9.4144ms 400 
SampleService.Web.Mvc> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
SampleService.Web.Mvc>       Connection id "0HLGPB44TBNED", Request id "0HLGPB44TBNED:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

Please help if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you use [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut and HttpDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#http-methods) attributes on your controller methods?

Comment: I tried putting them but it didn't matter. Plus, It's already working for postman, so I don't see the use in keeping them

Comment: @RobIII I know it shows a bad request, but it also says undocumented under 400. so I thought I should mention it.

Comment: Show us your controller.

Comment: Check the error in Logs.txt.

Comment: There is no controller for this application service.And I don't know where the Logs.Txt is

Comment: Try clearing your cookies.

Comment: see https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/3658#issuecomment-407193733 and https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=9892#p9892